# Config error with NamespaceHandler for XML

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

Why do I get this error (for my Appengine web app):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
```

When the servlet-context.xml file is there?

Comment: do you have the oxm jar in the classpath?